# Clarification on bit counter

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

This refers to the comment against the post - 
[Sorting 10 million integers with 1 MB space Solution explanation - Programming Pearls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7219651/sorting-10-million-integers-with-1-mb-space-solution-explanation-programming-p?rq=1)

'You can use 4 bits per counter for this, not 2 bytes. If you group counters you can even lower this value, for example if you group 3 counters, that's 10*10*10=1000 combinations and you need 10 bits (=1024 values) for that.'

Since I am not from computer science background,would appreciate help in explaining the technique behind tracking counters in 1/2  a byte.

Comment: `If each integer appears at most ten times, then we can count its occurence in a four-bit half byte.` The number 10 (ten) can be encoded using 4 bits, hence a half-byte. But 10 requires only `log2(10) ~= 3.32` bits to be represented, so you can pack several counters together to save even more space (as in the quote).

Comment: Perfect explanation - thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea is that you use [bit manipulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation) to exploit the fact that you have more bits at your disposal than are needed to represent the individual values you are storing.  This is most practical when you are using a programming language that intrinsically supports bit manipulation, such a C++.

For a given integer, it requires `log2(num)` bits to represent the value in [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number).  As a corollary, you can determine the largest integer that can be stored in a given number of bits with `2^n-1` where `n` is the number of bits.  So if we limit ourselves to 4 bits, the biggest number we can represent is 15.

For simplicity's sake, let's assume that the number of bits available in each value is 8 (1 byte).  And as you requested, we will use 4 bits for each stored value.  Also, the code that follows will be in C++.

### Helper Constants

These constants will help in the computations.

```
 const int PIECE_MASK_LOWER = 15  //All 4 lower bits set to 1
 //NOTE: 15 = 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2 + 2^3
 const int VALUE_SIZE = 4 //We're using 4 bits for each value
```

### Retrieving

Use [bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) logic to extract only the bits of the value you want.  Bitwise AND logic gives a value whose binary representation contains 1s where *both* of the operands had 1s.

**Retrieving the lower piece**

```
val = compositeVal & PIECE_MASK_LOWER
```

**Retrieving the upper piece**

This is the same as getting the lower piece; but you need to [right-shift the bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) first so that the bits of the target value are in the correct position for the bitwise AND operation.

```
val = (compositeVal >> VALUE_SIZE) & PIECE_MASK_LOWER
```

### Storing

Use [bitwise OR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) logic to apply the bits of the value you want to store to the byte in which you are storing it.  Bitwise OR logic gives a result whose binary representation contains 1s where *either* of the operands had 1s.

**Storing the lower piece**

```
compositeVal = compositeVal | val
```

**Storing the upper piece**

This is the same as storing the lower piece, except you need to [left-shift the bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bit_shifts) so that they are in position for the bitwise OR operation.

```
compositeVal = compositeVal | (val << VALUE_SIZE)
```

Note: if you are overwriting a piece in the composite value, you will have to clear the value that's already there.  Otherwise the bitwise OR operation will give you corrupted values.